# Download optimized image - Google Insight

Tags: pagespeed-insights

After google insight analysis, there was an option to download optimised contents (CSS, JS, Images). Now the option is not visible anywhere in the new design. Was it removed?

Could some one give a screenshot if it's available.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the case, but GPSI sometimes offers nothing to download,  if the analysis result is satisfactory.

Also GPSI is sometimes unhappy with its own files (images) it offers for download and re-optimizes them again, after you use them and re-test.